# How can I convert an array of objects in JSON to an array with values only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to convert

```
[{"document_id":"1"},{"document_id":"4"},{"document_id":"3"},{"document_id":"10"},{"document_id":"11"},{"document_id":"2"}]
```

**To**

```
["1","4","3","10","11","2"]
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use:

```
var arr = [{"document_id":"1"},{"document_id":"4"},{"document_id":"3"},{"document_id":"10"},{"document_id":"11"},{"document_id":"2"}];

var new_arr = arr.map(function(item) {
   return item.document_id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `for in` loop , `.splice()` , `Object.keys()`

```js
var arr = [{
  "document_id": "1"
}, {
  "document_id": "4"
}, {
  "document_id": "3"
}, {
  "document_id": "10"
}, {
  "document_id": "11"
}, {
  "document_id": "2"
}];

for (var prop in arr) {
  arr.splice(prop, 1, arr[prop][Object.keys(arr[prop])[0]]);
};
 
console.log(arr);
```